# Screen Tearing in Ubuntu 16.04 using APU A8-6410 Lenovo B40-45

Tags: 16.04, screen

When I browsing with Google Chrome, I got some Screen Tearing, and that is annoying my eyes of course, also when I play video on VLC, I got the same problem.
My Laptop Specification :
Processor A8-6410
VGA on board R5
RAM 6GB DDR3L

Please help me , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

The step are :

1. install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** from Ubuntu software
2. make sure that **Composite, OpenGL** and **Workarounds** ***checked***
3. open Composite and make sure that **Detect Refresh Rate and Unredirect Fullscreen Windows are *checked***
4. open Workarounds and make sure that Force complete redraw on **initital damage and Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint *checked***
5. Finish.